# How do I create a CSS mixin using the new `part` syntax?

Tags: css

I want to apply a number of CSS rules to different selectors, without creating additional selectors. In SCSS, this would be typically done with a `mixin`, eg:

```
@mixin gradient-text {
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    350deg,
    var(--dark-blue),
    var(--teal),
    var(--bright-green)
  );
}
```

Reading around the internet, there's lots of [references to making mixins with the CSS `apply` syntax](https://hashnode.com/post/creating-native-css-mixins-with-apply-rule-cinh1j54c01hla153n9x73770), but
https://caniuse.com/sr_css-apply mentions:

> @apply was briefly supported behind a flag in Chromium but has since been abandoned in favor of the ::part() selector.

[Reading about CSS part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) though it seems like it's not possible to use CSS part without modifying my HTML and [using web components, which have their own issues](https://dev.to/richharris/why-i-don-t-use-web-components-2cia).

**Is it possible to do a mixin in CSS, without modifying my HTML or JS, using `part`?**

Comment: If the DOM you are targeting is not part of a shadow tree then no.

Comment: Also, nothing wrong with web components. The linked articles author also says top level await is a footgun, which it is not.

Comment: @morganney you're free to add that as an answer. There's a few things wrong with web components mentioned in the article, but we can save that discussion for elsewhere.

Comment: There's a few things wrong wherever you look on the web platform @mikemaccana. Choices are usually made from personal bias, which is very human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MDN article you linked to, `::part` can only match elements within a [shadow tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM). Additionally, the [spec for the `::part`](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-shadow-parts/#part) states

> The ::part() pseudo-element only matches anything when the originating element is a shadow host.

Thus, if you wanted to leverage this pseudo-element for CSS mixins, you'd be better working with (developing) a native web component library. You may be able to use the corresponding `part` HTML attribute outside of the Shadow DOM to implement CSS mixins depending on your requirements.

When in doubt the best thing is to experiment. Here is an example of using `::part()` and `part` (HTML attr) inside and outside of a shadow DOM. Best to test [browser support on `part`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_part) as it is a relatively new technology. Moreover, seems there is still [ongoing questions about how multiple ident's should be supported](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4412), if at all.

```js
customElements.define('custom-thing', class CustomThing extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    
    const root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed'})
 
    root.append(document.getElementById('custom').content.cloneNode(true))
  }
})
```

```css
[part~="a"] {
  color: red;
}
[part~="b"] {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

p::part(a) {
  color: blue !important;
}

custom-thing::part(a) {
  color: green;
}
custom-thing::part(a)::after {
  content: 'A';
}
custom-thing::part(b) {
  color: orange;
}
custom-thing::part(a b) {
  /* does multiple ident values work? */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p part="a b">part</p>
<template id="custom">
  <style>
    p[part="a"] {
      color: aqua;
    }
  </style>
  <p part="a">part a</p>
  <p part="b">part b</p>
  <p part="a b">part a b</p>
</template>

<custom-thing></custom-thing>
```